# Enable/disable startup programs/script/services on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion

I upgraded my MacBook Pro to OS X Lion, and now the fans are working at high speed, even at very low loads.

I did a lot of things, resetting PRAM, SMC, etc, but the problem persists. It seems it has to do with Parallels or some other application.

I wonder how could I find out which programs/scripts/services are started at reboot on my MacBook. I'm not talking about just going to *User Accounts* in *System Preferences*. I mean the full list, like the one you get in a Linux machine.

Comment: "I mean the full list, like the one you get in a linux machine" -- I have yet to see something like that. Any such list *will* be incomplete.

Comment: flow, please make up your mind whether this is a troubleshooting question or you're asking about automatically starting programs. As it stands, it's a bit of both and *really* difficult to answer. I'm actually tempted to delete the first two paragraphs...

Comment: [A pretty classic XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) IMHO.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Seeing which processes are running

1. From the Terminal, using `ps ax`
2. Run *Applications » Utilities » Activity Monitor* and select *All Processes*. You can also exit them from there.

### Automatically starting processes

1. Those that are selected to *Open at Login* in the Dock
2. Those in *System Preferences » Accounts » Login Items* (actually, these include the ones from 1.)
3. The login hook for `loginwindow` [described here](http://support.apple.com/kb/Ht2420), read current value with `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook`
4. Some of those specified as part of a `launchd` script (or otherwise managed by `launchd`). List all with `sudo launchctl list`. See `man launchctl` for details.

Regarding the `launchd` lists, you can see their definition files in the `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDaemons` subdirectories of your system's `Library` directories:

- `/System/Library` (you probably shouldn't touch these)
- `/Library/` (usually for all users)
- `/Users/yourname/Library` (your own programs)

In the latter two libraries, check for anything suspicious. It's usually XML, so you can open and read them.

---

The problem here is, that you can run a single process that launches tons of others upon a certain condition, e.g. `cron` on OS X exists but is deactivated by default. Specify `@reboot` for a job, and it will be launched by `cron` upon system start.

Something similar applies to your shell configuration files `.bash_profile` etc., that can launch processes in the background as soon as you open Terminal.

Comment: sorry, I mean; there are some other programs and services that are started at boottime (do not know exactly when) like parallels, but they do not appear on those files

Comment: last comment; I notice that booting into safe mode, I have no problem at all, so it might be that something is loaded into normal mode that causes this problem. How could I do some find of "diff" to know this?

Comment: @flow Parallels is likely a kernel extension in `/System/Library/Extensions`. Command line tool names for handling those start with `kext`.

Comment: @flow I don't mind constructive comments, no matter how many.

Comment: Does `LoginHook` still exist? I get the following error when trying to read the value: *The domain/default pair of (/Users/[username]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow, LoginHook) does not exist*

Comment: Also check `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`